# Removing specific elements from global array on checkbox check and un-check with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push, splice

I am trying to update a global array when a user checks or un-checks checkboxes in a form.  The array will then be submitted to the server to update the checked options in the database.
I have got as far as pushing the IDs of the checked checkboxes into an array but am unsure how to remove them.

I have created a basic jsFiddle to demonstrate here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ArFuz/

PS - the array willbe properly namespaced later on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do this work on every click, just do it when the form is submitted - there is a :checked selector you can use also rather than selecting and iterating elements that your not interested in.

As jyoseph suggested - you could use serialize array here to build a name/value array

e.g

```
$('#submitButton').click( function(ev){

   var ids = [];

    $(':checkbox:checked').each( function(){

         ids.push(this.id);

    });

   //do something with ids

});
```

Comment: The issue is that there is pagination in the table.  Each time a page is called there is no post to updat ethe values.  Hence the global array and the need to update on every check/un-check.

Comment: @RyanP13 Ah - late breaking requirements news! With this info I would not have said the above!

Comment: P.S I would use .delegate rather than a click event on all checkboxes

Comment: apologies for that.  Under pressure and hurried the question.  A case of slowing down to speed up :)  And yes i would normally use delegate as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looping over all of the checkboxes every time, just empty the array at the beginning and only put checked items back in:

```
ids = [];

if (this.checked) {    
    ids.push(this.id);
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I swapped `$(this).is(":checked")` with the more efficient `this.checked` and `$(this).attr("id")` with the more efficient `this.id`.  The OP's code had a small error in it, which I also fixed. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be good with jQuery serializeArray() ([api link](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/))

```
$('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){

    // get all checked checkboxes
    var ids = $('myForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();

});
```

EDIT: [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/uguge4/2)